# How to compile a 32-bit C++ code on a default 64-bit compiler

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit, tasm

I am currently studying CP and have encountered a problem. I need to convert my C++ code to 32-bit TASM and use it inside an

```
__asm__(R"()");
```

inline assembly on a GNU 10.2 C++ 17 compiler with the default 64-bit compilation. The system is a Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) virtual machine on VMware Workstation 16.1.2 build-17966106 Pro (the host operating system is Windows 11, 64-bit, Pro, Central Processing Unit: i5-8300h). However, neither the command

```
gcc -m32 main.c -o main
```

nor

```
gcc -m32 main.cpp -o main
```

(even though I renamed the file to .cpp) have worked. The error messages follow.
Thanks in advance.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm4IG.png

Comment: Don't post error messages and code as image. From the error message it looks you don't have c++ compiler installed, only c. You need to install g++ package and compile c++ code with `g++` instead of `gcc`.

Comment: You'll need to install the 32-bit development libraries https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/gcc-multilib https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu

Comment: Thank You very much, I'll be right back asap and answer if it works.